Cannot render radial graph with phylotree.min.js (Rendering failed: Error: SVG element not found in #dynamic-tree)
I have been trying for the past few weeks to get phylotree.min.js to render data as a radial phylogenetic circular tree, like here. So far I have tried writing it from scratch and everyone online says I should use phylotree. However, I cannot even initialize it properly without getting an error relating to the object not being callable.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Radial Circular Phylogenetic Tree</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phylotree@1.0.0/dist/phylotree.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        #tree-container {
            width: 800px;
            height: 800px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tree-container"></div>
    <script>
        const newick = `((Grandchild1_1,Grandchild1_2)Child1,(Grandchild2_1,(GreatGrandchild2_2_1,GreatGrandchild2_2_2)Grandchild2_2)Child2)Root;`;

        const tree = new phylotree.phylotree(newick, {
            type: "circular"
        });

        tree.render({
            container: "#tree-container",
            width: 800,
            height: 800,
            layout: "radial", 
            "left-right-spacing": "fit-to-size",
            "top-bottom-spacing": "fit-to-size"
        });

        d3.selectAll(".node circle")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .style("fill", "#4285f4");

        d3.selectAll(".branch")
            .style("stroke", "#aaa")
            .style("stroke-width", "1.5px");

        d3.selectAll(".node text")
            .style("font-size", "10px")
            .style("fill", "#333");
    </script>
</body>
</html>


However, I cannot even get the graph to render. I've revised the code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Radial Circular Phylogenetic Tree</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phylotree@2.0.1/dist/phylotree.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        #tree-container {
            width: 800px;
            height: 800px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tree-container"></div>
    <script>
        // Define the Newick string
        const newick = `((Grandchild1_1,Grandchild1_2)Child1,(Grandchild2_1,(GreatGrandchild2_2_1,GreatGrandchild2_2_2)Grandchild2_2)Child2)Root;`;

        // Ensure compatibility between phylotree.js and D3.js v7
        // Replace extend with Object.assign if necessary
        if (typeof ___namespace !== 'undefined' && typeof ___namespace.extend === 'undefined') {
            ___namespace.extend = Object.assign; // Polyfill for extend
        }

        // Initialize the phylogenetic tree
        const tree = new phylotree.phylotree(newick, { type: "circular" });

        // Render the tree in the specified container
        tree.render({
            container: "#tree-container", // Match container ID
            layout: "radial",
            width: 800,
            height: 800,
        });

        // Style nodes and branches for better visibility
        d3.selectAll(".node circle").attr("r", 5).style("fill", "black");
        d3.selectAll(".branch").style("stroke", "black").style("stroke-width", "1px");
    </script>
</body>
</html>


but I get the errors:
phylotree.js:4263 Uncaught TypeError: ___namespace.extend is not a function
    at phylotree.js:4263:16
    at phylotree.js:4:78
    at phylotree.js:5:2

test_newick.html:40 Uncaught TypeError: phylotree.phylotree is not a constructor
    at test_newick.html:40:22 

UPDATE:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Phylotree Debug</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.7/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phylotree@2.0.1/dist/phylotree.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/phylotree@2.0.1/dist/phylotree.css" />
    <style>
        #tree-container {
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #dynamic-tree svg {
            border: 1px dashed red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tree-container">
        <div id="dynamic-tree"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            try {
                window.d3 = d3; // Ensure D3 is globally available
                console.log("D3.js version:", d3.version);

                // Simplest valid Newick data
                const newickData = "(A:1,B:1);";
                console.log("Initializing Phylotree...");
                const tree = new phylotree.phylotree(newickData);
                console.log("Phylotree instance initialized:", tree);

                // Ensure container exists
                const container = document.querySelector("#dynamic-tree");
                if (!container) {
                    throw new Error("#dynamic-tree container not found in the DOM.");
                }
                console.log("Container found:", container);

                // Manually create SVG if missing
                if (!container.querySelector("svg")) {
                    console.log("Manually creating SVG element...");
                    const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
                    svg.setAttribute("width", 600);
                    svg.setAttribute("height", 600);
                    container.appendChild(svg);
                }

                // Render the tree
                console.log("Rendering tree...");
                tree.render({
                    container: container, // Pass DOM element
                    width: 600,
                    height: 600,
                    "left-right-spacing": 50,
                    "top-bottom-spacing": 50,
                    "is-radial": true,
                });
                console.log("Rendering complete!");

                // Verify SVG creation
                const svg = container.querySelector("svg");
                if (svg) {
                    console.log("SVG successfully created:", svg);
                } else {
                    throw new Error("SVG element not found in #dynamic-tree");
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Rendering failed:", error);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


But now I get the error:
D3.js version: 4.13.0
test_newick.html:34 Initializing Phylotree...
test_newick.html:36 Phylotree instance initialized: lt
test_newick.html:43 Container found: <div id=​"dynamic-tree">​</div>​
test_newick.html:47 Manually creating SVG element...
test_newick.html:55 Rendering tree...
test_newick.html:64 Rendering complete!
test_newick.html:74 Rendering failed: Error: SVG element not found in #dynamic-tree
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (test_newick.html:71:27)


I think you need to include the underscore library - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/underscore.js

So that definitely helped with the error...but even though there are no more errors nothing is actually rendering.
